Question about Deformation Retractions in Fomenko and Fuchs
Working through Anatoly Fomenko and Dmitry Fuchs' "Homotopical Topology". As an offhand comment, they mention:
$A$ is a deformation retract of $X$ if and only if the inclusion map $A \rightarrow X$ is a homotopy equivalence.
Here are the definitions we're using: a retract is a continuous map $X \rightarrow A \subseteq X$, which fixes every point in $A$.
A deformation retract is a retract that is homotopic to the identity on $X$ (the homotopy does not necessarily need to fix every point in $A$; if it does, they call that a strong deformation retract). Here's the textbook phrasing:

"If a retraction $r : X \rightarrow X$ of X onto A is homotopic to the identity id$_X : X \rightarrow X$, then $A$ is called a deformation retract of $X$."

The definition of homotopy equivalence is the standard one (maps which are inverses up to homotopy).
One direction is easy; clearly if there's a deformation retract, then it forms a homotopy inverse for the inclusion.
I found myself surprisingly stuck in the reverse direction, though. If the inclusion is a homotopy equivalence, there's still no guarantee that the homotopy inverse has to be a retract (IE, no guarantee that its inverse has to fix points in $A$). For an explicit counterexample (not to the problem as a whole, but to the idea that the homotopy inverse of the inclusion must be a retract), consider the map $f : B_{1}(0) \subseteq \mathbb{C} \rightarrow B_{\frac{1}{2}}(0)$ given by $re^{i\theta} \mapsto \frac{r}{2}e^{i(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2})}$. Clearly this forms a homotopy inverse for the inclusion in the other direction, but it's also definitely not a retract.
Of course, in this case there's a much simpler homotopy inverse which is a retract, but I'm finding it hard to convince myself that this must be true in general, even for pathological topological spaces.

As written, the comment in their book is simply wrong. Take, for instance, $A=(0,1)\subset \mathbb R$. Then $A$ is not even a retract.

Ah, great counterexample. Thanks; I couldn't come up with one myself.

A related statement, though it doesn't seem this is where they were going, is that if $A\hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration to begin with, then it is a strong deformation retract iff it is a homotopy equivalence.
